# Reading from / Writing into a Text file in WP8 App

Tags: c#, file, xaml, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'm familiar with the *Data File Handling* concept involved in C, C++ and also have implemented it in *Console Applications* using the System.IO namespace and the necessary classes involved.

However, I am not able to do so in a Windows Phone 8 project.

What I'd like is to directly add an already created text file to my Windows Phone 8 project and perform the read and write operations as per my need.
*(Not to be confused with working with files through the Isolated Storage)*

I found some solutions where the file is read as a whole into one variable, however, this does not solve my purpose. **I want some sort of control in the file so that I can traverse to the exact line number and read the particular line into a local string variable. I'd also like to detect EOL and EOF.**

Is it possible to implement this to the exact level of detail that I require?

It would also be very helpful if you'd explain the difference between a text file present in the Isolated Storage and a text file directly present in the Project.

Kindly help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the [doc on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: I did read one with the information related to the  Storage Folder class. Is this the required [documentation link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes It is. Okay I just read again you question. You ask to read on line inside a file, true ? Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262965/how-do-i-read-a-specified-line-in-a-text-file) can help you.

Comment: The question/answer enclosed is tagged under C#. Are you sure it's applicable to the Windows Phone 8 design and structure?

Comment: Already did....does not work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried somethings on my own and came up with a solution to my problem.

Well the Data File handling mechanism in C# is pretty "intelligent" and the approach used for a WP8 App is similar to that of a Console Application.

**We use the System.IO namespace along with the StreamReader Class. The ReadLine() function is used to read a particular line. The reading process starts from the beginning of the file to the end of file. A counter is used for a specific line that needs to be read/fetched.**

Hope this is somewhat useful for someone who faced a similar problem.

The code that worked for me was:

```
var str = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Sample_File.txt", UriKind.Relative));
            StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(str.Stream);

            int x = 0;
            while(!sreader.EndOfStream)
            {
                x = x + 1;//increment the counter
                if(x==7) //counter value matches the required number
                {
                    //perform necessary tasks
                    break; //if required
                }
                sreader.ReadLine();
            }
```