# Read Line From Text File With More Than Int.Max Number of Lines

Tags: c#, file, ulong

I've Googled and looked at several answers but I haven't found a solution for this:
I have a .txt file that is comprised of more than int.max number of lines. How do I read a specific line whose number is > int.max? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262965/how-do-i-read-a-specified-line-in-a-text-file) question which has an answer listed as being able to

```
string line = File.ReadLines(FileName).Skip(14).Take(1).First();
```

But unfortunately the .Skip() extension method does not accept Long (or in my needed case ULong) parameters.

So I started looking to overload the .Skip extension (or more accurately make my own) to accept a ULong and found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1756533.aspx?how%20to%20create%20a%20extension%20method%20for%20IQueryable%20T%20Skip%20with%20a%20long%20parameter) Which didn't help me either as it pertains to Linq to entities.

Please can someone help me understand how to read a specific line from a text file where the line number is > int32.Max

Thanks

Comment: How much larger are we talking? Can you split the file in to chunks that are < int.max and do some math to get where you need to be in the 2nd, 3rd etc chunk?

Comment: @mjw yes I'm sure I could do that... I was hoping not to have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your own *Skip* as an extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MySkip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, ulong n)
{
    ulong i = 0;
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        if (i++ < n) continue;
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `yield break` is entirely superfluous.

Comment: @Eser is there a limit to what IEnumerable can handle?

Comment: @MegaMark it is a loop of *MoveNext*, and get *Current*. So there is no limit.

Comment: @MegaMark No.  There are limits to what particular implementations can handle, but the interface supports infinite sequences very cleanly.

Comment: You guys are lifesavers TYVM