# Reading particular lines in a text file

Tags: c#, file

I've been having some problems extracting particular lines in a txt file.
I'm using the file to store user names for a login program.

The program will know what line to go to in the text file but I don't know how to actually get the wanted line out and put the resulting string into a variable.

Code I'm using to pull file into a variable is:

```
string usernameFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Usernames.txt");
```

My real problem is that code two lines below doesn't work in my visual studios community version 2017:

```
File.ReadLine
```

I don't know if I need to install something else onto my visual studios but any method to be able to read a particular line of a txt file will be fine.

Comment: There's no such method as `File.ReadLine()` in the .NET library, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a specified line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262965/how-do-i-read-a-specified-line-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) instead. That gives you an array of strings, one for each line.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Usernames.txt");
string username = lines[2]; // or whatever.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to avoid reading the entire file:

```
var line = File.ReadLines("Usernames.txt").Skip(2).First();
```