# Read latest line from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to read all values from. But only from the last row which is newest. But I can't figure it out how to do it.

Im using streamreader now but that loops through the whole CSV file which can be very big.

I need to read two diffrent csv files(headers are the same but on diffrent location).

But how can I edit this code to only read from the last row? I have searched around but could not find anything that are the same as mine.

So this is how I been doing right now:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                var headerLine = reader.ReadLine();
                var headerValues = headerLine.Split(',');
                var serialNumber = headerValues[66];

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');

                    if (values[0] != "Index")
                    {
                        var analyseReport = new AnalyseReport();
                        analyseReport.SerialNumber = serialNumber;

                        foreach (var item in headerValues)
                        {
                            var headerName = item.Trim();
                            var index = Array.IndexOf(headerValues, item);

                            switch (headerName)
                            {
                                case "Index":
                                    analyseReport.Index = Convert.ToInt32(values[index].Trim());
                                    break;

                                case "Time":
                                    analyseReport.TimeStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(values[index].Trim());
                                    break;

                                case "Reading No":
                                    analyseReport.ReadingNo = Convert.ToInt32(values[index].Trim());
                                    break;
                                case "Duration":
                                    analyseReport.Duration = values[index].Trim();
                                    break;

                                case "Type":
                                    analyseReport.Type = values[index].Trim();
                                    break;

                                case "Units":
                                    analyseReport.Units = values[index].Trim();
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        analyseReportList.Add(analyseReport);

                    }
                }
                return analyseReportList;
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262965/how-do-i-read-a-specified-line-in-a-text-file

Comment: If you have fixed length lines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263032/2249175) is a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `File.ReadLines(path).Last()`:

```
string headerLine = File.ReadLines(path).First();
string lastLine = File.ReadLines(path).Last();
// ... (no loop)
```

These are LINQ methods so you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: But wouldn't this still read all lines, which is what the OP tried to avoid?

Comment: @PaulKertscher: you can't avoid that, but he would not _process_ all lines (as currently) and he would keep his code concise and readable. `Enumerable.First` does only read the first line, `Last` will "read" all lines but don't do anything with them, it only returns the last.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: @AndreasPettersson: keep in mind that you should use `ReadLines` not `ReadAllLines`. The latter indeed read all lines into memory.

Comment: "you can't avoid that" - why is that? You can read stream backwards until you meet newline character.

Comment: @Evk: you can try Jon Skeets approach which i havent tested. I doubt it makes your code more readable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/452945/284240 I also doubt that this is what OP really wanted. He just wanted to avoid processing all lines in the loop.

Comment: Not sure why it matters if it will make code more readable or not. OP wants to avoid reading whole (potentially huge) CSV file from hard drive for just 1 line (at least I think so), not to make code readable. And your solution (which is better than current OPs solution of course) still reads whole file from disk.

Comment: @Evk: I'm sure that the question arose because OP had a performance issue reading **and** processing all lines. If you look at his code you'll see that he splits all lines and probably also consume all(building an `AnalyseReport` for each). If you just do that with the last row the code will be much more efficient. Problem solved. As a side-effect his code will also become more readable

Comment: Well maybe you are right. But if so happens that OP has 10 GB CSV files and that still not be fast enough - good to let him know there are even faster approaches.

Comment: I have tried Tim Schmelter's code and it seems to work good with 11000 rows in the CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have fixed length lines, but can determine an upper limit of the length of your lines, you could use a heuristic to make reading the last line way more efficient.

Basically what to do is to move the current position of the file stream to `n` bytes from the end and then read until you've reached the last line.

```
private string ReadLastLine(string fileName, int maximumLineLength)
{
    string lastLine = string.Empty;

    using(Stream s = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        s.Seek(-maximumLineLength, SeekOrigin.End);

        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            string line;

            while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lastLine = line;
            }
        }
    }

    return lastLine;
}
```

For a 1.8 MB CSV it's about 100-200 times faster than the `File.ReadLines` method. Anyway, at the cost of a way more complicated code.

**Remarks:** While you *could* use this method to optimize reading the last line, *if* it is really the bottleneck, please use the way clearer and cleaner version of Tim Schmelter, if at any rate possible. Please remember the second rule of optimization: *"Don't do it, yet."*

Futhermore, to determine the maximum length of your lines, you have to be careful and consider the character encoding. Rather over- than under-estimate the line length.