# Compare two files starting from second line (nth line) in c#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to compare two txt files starting from 2 line (or nth line)? I have tried to search online but unable to find any way

I have got many examples to compare two files but all examples are related to entire files.

Right now I am using following code

```
    private static bool FileCompare(string file1, string file2)
    {
        int file1byte;
        int file2byte;
        FileStream fs1;
        FileStream fs2;

        if (file1 == file2)
        {
            return true;
        }

        fs1 = new FileStream(file1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        fs2 = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        if (fs1.Length != fs2.Length)
        {
            fs1.Close();
            fs2.Close();

            return false;
        }

        do
        {
            file1byte = fs1.ReadByte();
            file2byte = fs2.ReadByte();
        }
        while ((file1byte == file2byte) && (file1byte != -1));

        fs1.Close();
        fs2.Close();

        return ((file1byte - file2byte) == 0);
    }
```

Comment: Two loops, Linq, there are endless possibilities

Comment: You haven't even tried to compare the lines in the code you posted.

Comment: `file1 == file2` is not the smartest idea either, it's going to do a case-sensitive comparison. What if one path is lowercase and the other is uppercase?

Comment: Also, your entire code could be replaced in 3 lines or so

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how is your code relevant to what you want to achieve. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262965/how-do-i-read-a-specified-line-in-a-text-file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think to implement this is by using `File.ReadLines()` and some Linq:

```
private static bool FileCompare(string file1, string file2, int offset = 0)
{
    //Reads the lines, skips the "offset" number of lines
    var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(file1).Skip(offset);
    var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(file2).Skip(offset);

    //gets two collections of the differences, ignoring case
    var firstNotSecond = file1Lines.Except(file2Lines, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    var secondNotFirst = file2Lines.Except(file1Lines, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    //If there is nothing in both collections they are the same
    return !firstNotSecond.Any() && !secondNotFirst.Any();
}
```

### Better Version Edit

I have learned something new today, @AleksAndreev pointed out in the comments that [`SequenceEqual()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073(v=vs.110).aspx) exists.  My answer could be even more simplified:

```
private static bool FileCompareV2(string file1, string file2, int offset = 0)
{
    //Reads the lines, skips the "offset" number of lines
    var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(file1).Skip(offset);
    var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(file2).Skip(offset);

    return file1Lines.SequenceEqual(file2Lines, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
           file2Lines.SequenceEqual(file1Lines, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Slightly modified fiddle for both solutions [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O5lY0s)

Comment: Why not `file1Lines.SequenceEqual(file2Lines )`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev I have edited my answer to include `SequenceEqual()` it was your suggestion however so if you decide to make your own answer I will remove that edit from my answer.  Thanks for the knowledge bomb!