# C# Reading parts of txt file

Tags: c#, text, streamreader

I have txt file that I get from software that looks like this.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

-- YYYYYYYYYYYYYY ----------------------------------------------------------
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

-- YYYYYYYYY ---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 (2) BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
 (3) CCCCCCCCCCCCCC

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        Firmware : XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   Serial Number : 00000000000000
       Disk Size : 999 GB

-- XXXXXXXXXX --------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I need to read data only from this section:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        Firmware : XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   Serial Number : 00000000000000
       Disk Size : 999 GB

-- XXXXXXXXXX --------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried StreamReader like this:

```
StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(txtFile);
while (!sw.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sw.ReadLine();
    if (line.Contains("(1)"))
    {
        OtherFunction(line);
    }
}
sw.Close();
```

But that doesn't work well. I cannot use some function that would read only from for example line 20 to line 23. I need something to say to the SteamReader that he has to read from line that contains `------------------` to line that contains `-- XXXXXXXXXX ----`

Any help would be greatly apriciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262965/how-do-i-read-a-specified-line-in-a-text-file) solution. However I guess this method also load to the memorny the txt file.

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *Linq* and *query* for required lines, something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

var lines = File
  .ReadLines(txtFile)
  .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("(1)"))         // Skip all lines before "...(1)..." 
  .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("-------------------")) // -/- "----"
  .Skip(1)                                          // Skip "----" itself
  .TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains("XXXXXXXXXX"))  // Take all lines before "...XXXXXX..."
  .ToArray();                                       // Have lines as an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a StreamReader, I would use File.ReadAllLines() which returns an array of strings.

You can then traverse the array until you find the desired result extract and continue.
Eg:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(txtFile);
```